# Angular 2 ngClass - apply multiple classes, with class variables

Tags: angular, class

I'm trying to add variable-driven class(es) to an element, along with other classes using ngClass.

Example:

```
// inputExtraClass = 'form-control-sm'

// Working
<input class='form-control' [ngClass]="inputExtraClass" placeholder="Working">

// Not working
<input class='form-control' [ngClass]="{inputExtraClass: true}" placeholder="Not working">
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NGmgkk5UWkg1lEJ1DzYA?p=preview)

Comment: you should be using component level style class or add selector before the class to ensure that it is applied. [**answer**](https://plnkr.co/edit/bMzEZnaeukMPeJXAxXze?p=preview)

Comment: The class that is stored in the inputExtraClass variable is a bootstrap class, not a custom one.

Answer (score 12):

Providing a kind of complete answer to your question,

Do: `<input class='form-control' [ngClass]="{'inputExtraClass': true}" placeholder="Not working">`

and if you want more than one class or switch between classes you can also do something like

```
<input class='form-control' [ngClass]="{'inputExtraClass': true, 'notInputExtraClass': !true }" placeholder="Not working">
```

this way above, it will be either one class or the other

You can also aply any other variation you like using this, or make a property in your component like this one:

```
toggleClass: boolean = true;
```

and in your html:

```
<input class='form-control' [ngClass]="{ 'inputExtraClass': toggleClass, 'notInputExtraClass': !toggleClass }" placeholder="Not working">
```

same idea, and then you could create a method and change the toggleClass property or whatever :) hope it helped

Comment: inputExtraClass is a variable in the component (inputExtraClass = 'form-control-sm'). If I do 'inputExtraClass': true, it would mean inputExtraClass is the actual class name, no?

Comment: Should work as well, for example in one of my applications i have: [ngClass]="{ dropdown: !shouldDisplayDropdown }" and it's defined in the component like: dropdow: string ="dropdown"; and sorry that i can't play with your plunkr ATM, have a bad connection right now

Comment: Can you update this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NGmgkk5UWkg1lEJ1DzYA?p=preview)?

Comment: the pluker is not loading for me, but i will try

Comment: if you don't mix quoting classes with the ones coming from the component property it will work @MohammadAli

Comment: @MohammadAli, if you use a variable, the uniq way allow is [ngClass]="variable" (you can play with the variable in code like, e.g. variable="form-control "+this.active?'red':''. If you use a class you can concat class name and condition like [ngClass]="{'classname1":condition1,'classname2':condicion2}"

Answer (score 5):

You can use the "array form" (https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description) in this way:

```js
cond1 = true;
cond2 = false;
smClass = 'form-control-sm';
xlClass = 'form-control-xl';

<input class='form-control' [ngClass]="[ smClass, cond1 ? 'form-control-lg' : '', cond2 ? xlClass : '' ]">
```

This will be:

```js
<input class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-lg">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use expressions inside ngClass:

```html
<input class='form-control' [ngClass]="(addClassIfTrue) ? 'inputExtraClass' : ''" placeholder="Working">
```

Comment: Similar response to Alejandro, inputExtraClass is a variable in the component, not the actual name of the class so putting it in single quotes would not apply the actual class

Comment: That string is supplied by the user (empty string if not supplied), so cannot set it to null. Also, doing it this way [ngClass]="inputExtraClass" will not allow me to set multiple classes via ngClass.

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to **directly use the class name with the dynamic variables**, without any conditions, then they can use this way.

```
<div class="card-table second" ngClass="{{source}} {{currentMode}}">
```